# CSS selector not working +, ~

Tags: html, css, hover

this is driving me crazy :

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x fcc1" style=""></i>
  <i class="fa fa-whatsapp fa-stack-1x fa-inverse fccc1"></i>
</span>
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x fcc2" style=""></i>
  <i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-stack-1x fa-inverse fccc2"></i>
</span>

<style>
.fccc1:hover, .fccc2:hover, {
color:#115ebb!important;
}
.fccc1:hover + .fcc1 {
color:white!important;  
}
.fccc2:hover + .fcc2 {
color:white!important;  
}
</style>
```

The first CSS rule for the hover is working perfectly.
However the second and third css rule to change an other class when hovered is not working. I dont see any errors in the code and to my understanding this should work. I also tried with out the + and with a ~ selector.

Any help appriciated.

Comment: Sorry misread the class names and hence the wrong comment earlier. The element with `class='fcc1'` is above the element with `class='fccc1'` in the DOM and CSS selectors cannot traverse the DOM upwards. You either have to interchange the order of the elements or use JS.

Comment: CSS selectors cannot traverse the DOM upwards.  <== Makes sense to me and is probably the answer.

Comment: There is a trick to traverse upwards, visually, using `flex` and `order` ... should I post an answer for you with that?

Comment: If I understand you want a trick like this https://jsfiddle.net/kedkavzt/ ?

Comment: @Oriol OP isn't asking for a parent selector ... it's asking *to traverse upwards* / siblings as LGSon points

Comment: Posted an answer showing how-to

Comment: @DaniP OK, sorry, I got confused because the concept is the same. The proper duplicate is [Is there a “previous sibling” CSS selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1817792/1529630)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a trick to traverse upwards, visually, using `flex` and `order`

```css
body {
  background: gray;
}
.fa-stack {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.fa-stack i:nth-child(1) {
  order: 2;
}
.fa-stack i:nth-child(2) {
  order: 1;
}
  
.fccc1:hover, .fccc2:hover {
color: #115ebb!important;
}
.fccc1:hover + .fcc1 {
color: white!important;  
}
.fccc2:hover + .fcc2 {
color: white!important;  
}
```

```html
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-whatsapp fa-stack-1x fa-inverse fccc1">Second</i>
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x fcc1" style="">First</i>
</span>
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-stack-1x fa-inverse fccc2">Second</i>
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x fcc2" style="">First</i>
</span>
```

Comment: Harry, DaniP and LGSon, thanks you totally understood my problem and LGSon took the time to post a detailed example how to solve.

Answer (score 0):

`div + p`   - Selects all `<p>` elements that are placed immediately after `<div>` elements

For reference - [CSS Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#Combinators)

Answer (score 0):

Your first rule handles both `.fccc1` and `.fccc2`, which both exist.

Your second rule, though, is for an `.fccc1` element following another `.fccc1` element. In your case, that doesn't exist. The preceeding element is `.fcc1` instead. Your rule would need to be:

```
.fcc1:hover + .fccc1
```